# Programming Phoenix YouTube Video Error - Videos Won't Play

Tags: javascript, youtube, elixir, youtube-javascript-api, phoenix-framework

I'm working through the Programming Phoenix book and I'm getting an error with the YouTube video player.

Here's my `web/static/js/player.js` file:

```
let Player = {
  player: null,

  init(domId, playerId, onReady){
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
      this.onIframeReady(domId, playerId, onReady)
    }
    let youtubeScriptTag = document.createElement("script")
    youtubeScriptTag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api"
    document.head.appendChild(youtubeScriptTag)
  },

  onIframeReady(domId, playerId, onReady){
    this.player = new YT.Player(domId, {
      height: "360",
      width: "420",
      videoId: playerId,
      events: {
        "onReady": (event => onReady(event) ),
        "onStateChange": (event => this.onPlayerStateChange(event) )
      }
    })
  },

  onPlayerStateChange(event){ },
  getCurrentTime(){ return Math.floor(this.player.getCurrentTime() * 1000) },
    seekTo(millsec){ return this.player.seekTo(millsec / 1000) }
}
export default Player
```

and I'm importing it like this in `web/static/js/app.js`:

```
import Player from "./player"
let video = document.getElementById("video")

if(video) {
  Player.init(video.id, video.getAttribute("data-player-id"), () => {
    console.log("player ready!")
  })
}
```

I'm seeing the "player ready!" message in the javascript console; however, the videos won't play. They give me an error that looks like this:

[image]

How can I fix this so that videos will play?

Answer (score 1):

The error was actually from my watch view - I forgot the question mark in the regex before `<id>` so the player_id was not being set correctly:

```
defmodule Rumbl.WatchView do
  use Rumbl.Web, :view

  def player_id(video) do
    ~r{^.*(?:youtu\.be/|\w+/|v=)(?<id>[^#&?]*)}
    |> Regex.named_captures(video.url)
    |> get_in(["id"])
  end
end
```